I'm looking for a SQL statement to copy all details from Product A to Product B
I have Table_P that has columns Product, region, salesperson, production date, end date.  (There are other columns, but those fields don't matter to me).  Product_X has 6 rows:  6 regions, 3 different salespeople and 6 date sets (production date and end date).   I want to add a new product, Product_Y to the table, and line by line mirror what Product_X has listed for each column to Product_Y (region, salesperson, production date, end date).  I also want to update the existing Product_W, adding all of the same data that I added to Product_Y had without loosing any of the existing unique entries for Product_W.
I tried using this:
INSERT INTO Table_P
    (PRODUCT, REGION, SALESPERSON, PROD_DATE, END_DATE)
  SELECT 'PRODUCT_W', REGION, SALESPERSON, SYSDATE(), TO_DATE ('31-12-9999', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  FROM Table_P
  WHERE PRODUCT = 'PRODUCT_X'

This works, but it also adds records from PRODUCT_X that already match what's in PRODUCT_W, resulting in duplicates.  I need to add a WHERE NOT... or something to check for existing matches and skip those.
This sql statement needs to run in Snowflake - if that helps.

It would be helpful if you edited your question and provided sample data, along with the expected result of that sample data (what the inserted data should look like versus what it actually looks like with your query, so we can better understand your problem)

What are the columns that make up the unique combination, if you have those then you can put that in the where clause to exclude 'Product_W'already added or you can use Merge

I changed "PLSQL" to "SQL" in the title because I thought this was an Oracle question with the Snowflake tag. Reading the post shows it's for Snowflake, and PL/SQL is specific to Oracle.

-- Insert data from Product_X to Product_W, avoiding duplicates
INSERT INTO Table_P (PRODUCT, REGION, SALESPERSON, PROD_DATE, END_DATE)
SELECT 'PRODUCT_W', REGION, SALESPERSON, PROD_DATE, END_DATE
FROM Table_P AS px
WHERE PRODUCT = 'PRODUCT_X'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM Table_P AS pw
      WHERE pw.PRODUCT = 'PRODUCT_W'
        AND pw.REGION = px.REGION
        AND pw.SALESPERSON = px.SALESPERSON
        AND pw.PROD_DATE = px.PROD_DATE
        AND pw.END_DATE = px.END_DATE
  );

Inserting data from Product_X to Product_W, avoiding duplicates:
This query checks if a similar row already exists in Product_W before inserting it.
The NOT EXISTS clause ensures that only rows that do not already exist in Product_W are inserted.
It compares the REGION, SALESPERSON, PROD_DATE, and END_DATE columns to ensure no duplicates.
I hope this helps

that's what I needed - thank you sir
